# Hover div flickers when rolling mouse over

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a div that appears when hovering over another div.

However when I try to move the mouse over the div that appears it flickers.
I understand this is happening because of my CSS, but can not figure out what I should do to rectify.

```css
.hoverbase {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.hovertop {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hoverbase a:hover+.hovertop {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class='hoverbase'>
  <a href=http://www.google.com.au>
    <img src='https://fakeimg.pl/300x300/949598/888888/' /></a>
  <div class='hovertop'>
    <a href=http://google.com.au>
      <h2>Project HA</h2>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmoore91/gf4fwyf2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to be aware, `.hovertop` flickers because of quick alternation between hovering and not hovering. When `.hovertop` is visible and the mouse is over it, the `:hover` action of `.hoverbase` is cancelled and `.hovertop` disappears. At that point, `.hovertop` is no longer covering `.hoverbase` and the `:hover` action is reinstated. This alternation happens quickly and repeats forever as long as your mouse is over `.hovertop`, resulting in a flickering effect.

Include `.hovertop` in your `:hover` state selector. That way, it will remain visible whether the mouse is over `.hoverbase` or `.hovertop`.

```css
.hoverbase a:hover + .hovertop,
.hovertop:hover { /* << added this */
    visibility:visible; 
 }
```

In English, this translates to: If the mouse is over `.hoverbase` OR `.hovertop`, show `.hovertop`.

Working example:

```css
.hoverbase {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.hovertop {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hoverbase a:hover+.hovertop,
.hovertop:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class='hoverbase'>
  <a href=http://www.google.com.au>
    <img src='//via.placeholder.com/350x150' /></a>
  <div class='hovertop'>
    <a href=http://google.com.au>
      <h2>Project HA</h2>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```